# National characters in SyncFusion Edit Control [WinForms]

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, utf, syncfusion

I installed the SyncFusion edition for WinForms and I have a problem with national characters in the editor.

Characters are able to properly load when it is stored in the BOM file. But when it is no BOM there such signs appear .

Has anyone already had this problem and how to solve it?

File with BOM

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg8iU.png]

File with out BOM

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi2gC.png]

I intend to whether it is the BOM files opened correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with EditControl. Please report the problem in the syncfusion website in the below link, you can expect the solution at the earliest.

Link : https://www.syncfusion.com/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=/support/directtrac